# Scala Postgres IN Operator

Tags: postgresql, scala, typesafe-activator

I'm developing a web application based on [Activator and Postgres](https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async).

I am trying to perform the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t_0
WHERE t_0.category IN (?)
```

then to populate the query I am using the following Scala code

```
val readQuery = """ SELECT * FROM table t_0 WHERE t_0.category IN (?) """
val categories = Array("free time", "living")
val insertValues = Array(categories)
val queryResult = await { connection.sendPreparedStatement(readQuery, insertValues) }
```

Even though there are some records in the database I always get an empty set, I have already tried with some forms of Array[Byte], but I have never managed to get results.

Does anybody have some tips or trick that I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want an `Array[Array[String]]` as a parameter for `IN`? Would it not be sufficient an `Array[String]`, like `categories`?

Comment: no it is not possible to do pass the values that way, if you use `connection.sendPreparedStatement(readQuery, categories)` you actually pass 2 values when the query expects only 1 and then you get an exception at runtime